# Facebook Canvas JavaScript Links Don't Work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, firefox, iframe

We are using ASP.NET for our Canvas Page, however none of the link buttons (JavaScript Post Backs) work when using FireFox.

After a bit of investigation it appears that any javascript link i.e. <a href="javascript:..."> will not run.

When viewing the iFrame outside of Facebook the links work as expected.

Bizarrely javascript on an "onclick" event does work correctly.

Facebook Canvas: http://apps.facebook.com/ukflive/test.aspx

Any thoughts on why this is happening, and how to resolve this? Other browsers such as Safari and Chrome do not have this issue.

Many Thanks,
Ady

Answer (score 1):

In some versions of firefox i've met same problem but i wasn't able to find out reason of problem since i've seen your question. thank you for this :). In my opinion it is a firefox bug working with iframes, and it is related with security concerns.

i've changed all <`a href="javascript:anyJSFunction()">` codes to `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="anyJSFunction">` and it works for my application.